# Ubuntu 16.04 software center install and remove buttons do not work

Tags: software-center

I've installed ubuntu 16.04 (unity) on my new computer, and for the past few hours have been trying to find someone else asking about this problem, but couldn't.
the software center pretends to start installing new applications, but then the bar just stays stuck at zero with nothing else happening.
Stranger still, few applications did look like they installed correctly, but do not show up when I look for them in the Dash, and then when clicking the remove button nothing happens.
Any suggestions?
BTW, the icons with the stuck installation bars disappear when I log out/restart.